# How to reverse steps in Velocity.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, velocity.js

Is there a way to chain animations together in `velocity.js` and then reverse back through them in sequence. I know you can reverse the last chained velocity animation but how do you step through the previous calls.

For example:

```
// Animate an SVG element with a mix of standard CSS properties and SVG-specific properties.
$("#rect")
    .delay(500)
      .velocity({ x: "+=200", y: "25%" })
    .velocity({ fillGreen: 255, strokeWidth: 2 })
      .velocity({ height: 50, width: 50 })
    .velocity({ rotateZ: 90, scaleX: 0.5 })

.velocity("reverse", { delay: 250 });
```

This will only reverse the last step, the rotation. How can you reverse through the others in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with current implementation, however, you could transform the above code into a "sequence" of calls and use the `RunSequence()` API of the [UI Pack](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#uiPack) and then reverse that Array and run it again to get the reverse effect.